# Rethinkdb Use existing value if branch evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Using branch update logic in rethinkdb. I am needing to update a value based on wether another value matches and then set the appropriate value. If the values are the same it should use the existing value.

```
r.db('testdb').table('great_table').get(1).update(source => {
  return r.branch(source('some_other_id').eq(1), {read: false}, /* use existing value */);
})
```

Tried the following:

```
r.db('testdb').table('great_table').get(1).update(source => {
  return r.branch(source('some_other_id').eq(1), {read: false}, source('checked'));
})
```

The error I received when I tried this is:

```
{
  "deleted": 0 ,
  "errors": 1 ,
  "first_error":  "Inserted value must be an OBJECT (got BOOL): false" ,
  "inserted": 0 ,
  "replaced": 0 ,
  "skipped": 0 ,
  "unchanged": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are trying to pass `bool` where Rethink expecting object.

So, your query should look like this (depends in which field you want save `source('checked')` value):

```
r.db('testdb').table('great_table').get(1).update(source => {
  return r.branch(source('some_other_id').eq(1), {read: false}, {read: source('checked')});
})
```